# Как перемещать элементы для текущего элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть карточки, в которых необходимо переместить один элемент в другой, мне это удалось, однако же происходит дублирование элементов от других карточек.

```js
$('.sticker').appendTo('.card-bottom');
```

```css
.card {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.sticker {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new</small>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new</small>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Пробовал вот так:**

```
    $('.card', function () {
    $(this).find('.sticker').appendTo('.card-bottom');
});
```

Прошу подсказать, пояснить как можно перемещать элементы без дублирования.

Comment: Ты делаешь appendTo во все элементы с классом card-bottom. Попробуй добавить ещё раз this или раздели на два этапа, 1) скопировал в переменную и удалил  2) добавил в новый блок

Comment: Объясните нормально что и как должно происходить?

Comment: Элемент со словом "new" должен переместиться в блок с классом "card-bottom"

Comment: @ДмитрийАнисько

Пробовал вот так:

$('.card', function () {
        let inTo = $(this).find('.sticker');
        let toIn = $(this).find('.card-bottom');

        inTo.appendTo(toIn);
});

Answer (score -1):

Смотря как Вы хотите перемещать их. Можно получить все элементы с классом .card-bottom .sticker и вставлять уже в нужное место используя порядковый номер.

```js
    $('.card', function () {
        var c = $('.sticker');
        var z = $('.card-bottom');
        $(this).find(c[0]).appendTo(z[0]); // Где 0 - это номер элемента
});
```

```css
.card {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.sticker {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new</small>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new</small>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если для каждого элемента

```js
    $('.card', function () {
        var c = $('.sticker');
        var z = $('.card-bottom');
        for (let i = 0; i < c.length; i++){   // Тут считаем количество элементов с классом .sticker 
            $(this).find(c[i]).appendTo(z[i]);
        }
});
```

```css
.card {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.sticker {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new</small>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new</small>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну у вас не работает так как надо, дубль происходит.

Comment: @Alexander где же тут происходит дубль? Вы комментарии читали?

Answer (score -1):

На данный момент нашел такое решение, однако, чувствую, что оно тяжеловато будет для страницы у которой очень много карточек будет:

```js
$('.card').each(function() {
  let inTo = $(this).find('.sticker');
  let toIn = $(this).find('.card-bottom');

  inTo.appendTo(toIn);
});
```

```css
.card {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.sticker {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new</small>
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new2</small>
    <h1>TITLE 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT 2</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="card">
  <div class="card-panel">
    <small class="sticker">new 54</small>
    <h1>TITLE 3</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="card-bottom">
    <div class="text">TEXT 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вам что, `.sticker` надо просто вниз переносить?

Comment: @InDevX да, вниз, пока нашел такое решение, но чувствую что оно тяжелое будет для огромного числа карточек.